# How can I light up 3 LEDs in sequence but only one at a time?

Tags: led, current, pulse

I have 3 LEDs in a row on a breadboard. I want to simulate a visual depiction of a current pulse by lighting up LED #1, then turning that off and lighting up LED #2, then turning that off and lighting up LED #3 then turning that off. How can I achieve this effect? To keep things simple, assume that it is irrelevant whether this process repeats endlessly or if it is activated based on some event. Also assume that only simple components are available, i.e. I probably can't use any component that a PhD in Electrical Engineering would consider "the most optimal component to use in this situation", as that would probably be too complex. The "most complex" components I have available are things along the lines of op amp, transistors (bipolar, FET), comparators, MUX's, and DAC/ADC.

Summary of requirements:

1. LEDs must only light up one at a time in sequence
2. Must have a way to adjust the speed at which they light up
3. Cannot do this by mechanical methods

Comment: A PhD in EE doesn't have access to a few MCU's???  ....I'm stunned.

Comment: Your image has three LEDs in series. Since the same current must flow through all three LEDs they must illuminate at the same time.

Comment: @Transistor that's funny, considering your name is _Transistor_.

Answer (score 4):

here is a mechanical way

just drag the lead across, contacting each LED in turn

not meant as an answer (it is the only way to include a schematic)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBzNOe.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

---

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEc2aq.png)</sup>

*A variation on the them. Use a ball-bearing running on two wire rails - one segmented with each LED connected to a segment - to switch the LEDs in sequence.*

Comment: I took the liberty of modifying your idea and adding an alternative version. I hope that's OK.

Comment: @Transistor, very nice .... the ball bearing channel could be circular, and it could be cat powered https://www.ebay.com/itm/Interactive-Cat-Toy-Crazy-Donut-Chase-Ball-Track-with-Mouse-on-Spring-Chaser-/251741836624

Answer (score 3):

What you want is an ***LED chaser***.

There are a few basic ways this is done.

1. Mechanical. That doesn't lend itself to repeating or automation.
2. Build a circuit of flip flops.
3. Use a CD4017 Decade counter, looping the 3rd output to the reset. Basically a pre-built flip-flop circuit. Just add a 555 timer.
4. Use a 50 cent micro controller that you can get started programming for under 5 bucks. MSP430, Arduinos, etc. This is how many people would do it today, ***not just PhDs***.

How you physically arrange the LEDs has nothing to do with how you control them electronically btw.

Comment: the OP wants to simulate the propagation of an electrical pulse. that is why the LEDs are in a row.

Comment: @jsotola yes. We all know.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious way to do this is with a microcontroller.  Even the tiny and cheap PIC 10F200 can do this:

[image]

This processor has a internal oscillator, so needs nothing more than power applied to run the code.  You can program it to light the LEDs in any combination and sequence.

For a more tedious, klunky, and less advanced approach, you can use a shift register as the basis for sequencing thru the LEDs.  Wire up the shift register so that it is circular, and initialize it with a single 1 bit.  Each clock pulse, the 1 output will shift to the next bit.  The speed of running thru the pattern is dependent on the clock speed.

Answer (score 1):

Use two PNP transistors to create a current mirror.  Use a capacitor to integrate the current to create a linear voltage ramp.

Use a set of comparators to turn on the LEDs when the ramp output is between certain voltages.

1)  First LED  0V to 1.66V.

2)  Second LED 1.66V to 3.33V

3)  Third LED 3.33V to 5.0V

Connect the negative side of the first LED between to the output of the 1.66V through a 1K resistor.  Connect the other side to ground.

The positive end of the second LED to the output of the second comparator through a 1K resistor.  Connect the other side to the output of the 3.33V comparator.

Connect positive side of the third LED to the output of the 3.33V comparator through a 1K resistor.  Connect the other side of the third LED to ground.

The LEDs will then turn on/off in sequence when you apply power.  You can adjust the timing either by changing the 100K resistor or the 100uF capacitor.  The basic pattern can be extended to any number of LEDs by just using more comparators.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVwx5Q.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You don't need amps, transistors, comparators, muxes or dac/adc, just use a (simple) microprocessor.

When using a microprocessor: Just connect with 3 different GPIO (generic) pins, one led to a separate GPIO, with a resistor (like 470 ohm) before or after each led.

By setting the output of a GPIO pin to either High or Low per pin, you can decide whether to light the LED or not.

Use something like this:

[image]

If you don't have experience with microprocessors, buy an Arduino Uno, the first example is to blink a light ... if you can do that, duplicate the circuit for each LED instead of one LED and you get the idea. There are also tons of moving lights (like the Knight Rider led) which is sort of what you want (but even simpler).

Comment: Wait, in your final note, you say that I *won't* be able to light one while the others are off. However, this is the effect I am trying to achieve. I was thinking maybe sending a short current pulse through the 3 LED's in series. Could that possibly light up/turn off the 3 LED's in sequence?

Comment: So your circuit does not work, try the one I added in the picture. And put pins 11, 12 and 13 to high alternately.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers - Your answer is confusing. First you state that a microprocessor *will* work, then you say "You never be able to light one LED while having the other LEDs off or vice versa", then you show a diagram of a circuit that absolutely *can* light individual LEDs. I assume you were trying to explain that the *Blink* example will not light individual LEDs. But that is not obvious.

Comment: @Bort The blink example will light one LED, but because each LED has a different GPIO pin, you can control them individually, which is what you need. If you control all LEDs from a single GPIO pin, they are either all on or all off.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers - I am fully aware of how it works. I'm telling you that your answer is confusing and unorganized. That is why OP whatwhatwhat asked you to clarify. Again: First you state that a microprocessor **will work**, then you say "You **never** be able to light one LED while having the other LEDs off or vice versa", then you show a diagram of a circuit that **will work**. The image you posted immediately follows the blink example, but the image is shows three different GPIO pins being used.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers The only reason I understand what you are saying is because I'm already familiar with Arduinos and the Blink example. Someone who has not seen the Blink example will not understand what you are talking about because your paragraphs are confusing. It needs to be clear that by using three different GPIO pins, the user **can** light individual LEDs, they just need to write the code as such.

Comment: If you are already familiar with the blink example, you didn't think about using 3 different GPIO pins?

Comment: @MichelKeijzers - **I already told you** I understand. I'm telling you that **your answer is confusing to novices**. Either fix it, or don't. I don't know why you won't address that your answer is confusing. You are making me repeat everything I've already said.

Comment: I updated my answer. Hope you like it better now.

Comment: @Bort, the OP had a circuit diagram that had the three LEDs in series. that is why it would be impossible to light only one (the diagram has been removed) ... i do not think that people have to go and rewrite their answers just because the OP decides to make changes in the question

Comment: @jstola - This is regardless of OP's diagram. I was talking about Michel's answer lacking continuity. This is something related to writing (composition).  I stated why several times. If I start talking about X but then describe Y without stating so, and then I show a diagram of X, people may not understand that the Y comment was not about X. (Just as whatwhatwhat said "wait...") So I know I'm not alone in my continuity issue. I didnt mean for this to get so out of hand. I was just trying to explain the continuity problem.

Comment: @Bort: updated my answer, otherwise feel free to edit it the way you like it better.

Answer (score 0):

Have the 1 light hit a phototransistor, which in turn lights the 2nd LED.  This one would shine on the next phototransistor and so on.  Having a small capacitor on each leg would look like consecutive pulses.

Comment: How would you control the speed at which they light up? How would turn off the LED sequentially!?

Answer (score -1):

[image][image]

I am not very techy so this took me a while to find - because I didn't know what I was looking for. I am making a fancy 'light show' that has a sequence of lights come on when you throw switch. Easier said than done!

These are both TIMER RELAYS. The smaller one controls 2 circuits the larger one  controls 8. You can buy one that does 3 or 4. The double would work for you. I paid about $8 on Amazon.

They look daunting but they are not. I am NOT tech savvy but I muddled through. Power goes to the relay which you program with a delay. MAKE SURE TO CHECK TIMER RELAY WORKS IN 10ths of SECONDS. So your first bulb is on a regular circuit, no delay, 2nd and 3rd bulb on the same circuit but you break the positive, shove it in relay set output A to 0.2 seconds and B to 0.4 seconds ... or whatever. You also need to set the time they go off. My lights are all 0.1 second apart but delay off differently - so from the light switch leds span out along the wall and around the room to the main light at the far end (which fades on - its kinda cool!!!) The effect is like a chain reaction or digital dominoes from the switch to the main light feature.